# What does sizeof(int**) mean?

Tags: c

I am new to C. I saw this line in a program:

```
grid = calloc(nx,sizeof(int**));
```

I read that `int**` means a pointer to a pointer, but what is meant by `sizeof(int**)`??

Comment: [was this so tough?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof)

Comment: @EOF thank you for adding entertainment to my day.

Comment: @EOF: "*... assumes that NULL must be bitwise zero.*" From what do you conclude this? What am I missing? :-S

Comment: @alk: `calloc()` rather than `malloc()`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I know what sizeof is. I understand what sizeof(int) means. I didn't know what it meant for a pointer.

Comment: Aahh, yes, sure, now I got the "joke" ... :} @EOF

Comment: @secluded: `int` is a type, `int*` as well, `int**` as well, ...

Comment: @alk: To be fair, the programmer *could* have used `calloc()` to avoid overflow when computing `sizeof(type) * number_of_elements`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(int **)` tells you how many bytes an `int **` is, similarly to how `sizeof(int *)` tells you how many bytes an `int *` is.  They just have different levels of indirection.

Comment: Is it correct to say that sizeof(int**)=sizeof(int*) since in both cases, we only need to put an address in the memory.
Also, does it make any difference if you put a space between int and **?
Thanks for the help

Comment: @secluded: No.  It's not guaranteed that `int *` and `int **` require the same amount of storage.  On most modern architectures they do, but it doesn't have to be universally true.

Comment: In practice, most likely, however that doesn't necessarily have to be the case.  The standard doesn't say they have to be the same.

Comment: @secluded; Spaces do not matter: `int**` is the same as `int* *`, is the same as `int **`, is the same as `int * *`, ...

Answer (score 3):

The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes of storage required by its operand.  The operand is either an expression or a type enclosed in parentheses.  In this case, the operand is the type `int **`, which is "pointer to pointer to `int`".

Assuming `grid` has been declared as

```
int ***grid;
```

then that can be rewritten as

```
grid = calloc(nx, sizeof *grid);
```

Comment: Nit: "*... in this case the operand is the type `int **`*" In fact as its a type the size of should be taken, the operand is `(int**)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
How did you come to the conclusion that `grid` should be declared as `int ***grid`?? I'd really appreciate it if you could also explain what this declaration means. You are right, I found this declaration in my code!

Comment: @secluded:  Whenever you dynamically allocate an object of type `T` through `malloc` or `calloc`, you always assign the resulting pointer to an object of type `T *`. If you allocate a block of `int`s, you assign the result to an `int *`.  If you allocate a block of `int *`s, you assign the result to an `int **`.  And if you allocate a block of `int **`s, you assign the result to an `int ***`.

Answer (score 2):

The `sizeof` expression is just the number of bytes needed to represent a pointer-to-pointer-to-`int`.  Presumably, whoever wrote the code is looking to allocate enough memory to store `nx` such pointers.